# How to turn network connection off in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, networking

I doubt network connection cause a specific program in eclipse(it trys to download some xml stuff from specific domain,but this domain is blocked here),and after googling,I didn't find a way,so how to turn it off?

Comment: You're not giving enough details, but adding the host with a dummy IP in `/etc/hosts` or `%WINDIR%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` may be the way to go.

Comment: I just want to stop eclipse to connect to network,but keep other apps connect normally